# How to clear string with fill pointer?

Tags: common-lisp

Here's an example I saw at the [Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_w_out_.htm):

```
(setq fstr (make-array '(0) :element-type 'base-char
                             :fill-pointer 0 :adjustable t))
(with-output-to-string (s fstr)
    (format s "here's some output"))
```

So then `fstr` holds `here's some output` Q: How could you do a simple clear/reset on `fstr`in the case you want to start over and put something new in it, that is, not concatenate more onto it? Or would I just have to redo the top expression where `fstr` is being set up?

Comment: just to clarify, there's no *input* stream here.  There's an array (which is also a string, because of its element type), which has a fill pointer.  **with-output-to-string** creates a character *output* stream that sends its output to a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the *fill pointer*:

```
CL-USER 3 > (setq fstr (make-array '(0) :element-type 'base-char
                                   :fill-pointer 0 :adjustable t))
""

CL-USER 4 > (with-output-to-string (s fstr)
              (format s "here's some output"))
NIL

CL-USER 5 > fstr
"here's some output"

CL-USER 6 > (setf (fill-pointer fstr) 0)
0

CL-USER 7 > fstr
""

CL-USER 8 > (with-output-to-string (s fstr)
              (format s "here's some more output"))
NIL

CL-USER 9 > fstr
"here's some more output"
```

You can also call `adjust-array` to actually change the array size.

```
CL-USER 16 > (setf (fill-pointer fstr) 0)
0

CL-USER 17 > (adjust-array fstr 0)
""
```

Answer (score 7):

There are two orthogonal concepts interacting here.  The first is that vectors (strings, one dimensional arrays, etc.) can have a [*fill pointer*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_f.htm#fill_pointer):

> **fill pointer** n. (of a vector) an integer associated with a vector that
>   represents the index above which no elements are active. (A fill
>   pointer is a non-negative integer no larger than the total number of
>   elements in the vector. Not all vectors have fill pointers.)

When you're looking at a string, the fill pointer is essentially the length of the string, but allows the underlying array to actually contain more data (*which **is** still accessible*;  this may be important depending on the application).

Then, there are lots of ways that you can manipulate the content of a vector with a fill pointer.  For *strings*, there's a useful one provided by [**with-output-to-string**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_w_out_.htm), which creates a character steam that sends character output to the string.

> **with-output-to-string** creates a character output stream, performs a series of operations that may send results to this stream, and then
>   closes the stream.

So, you can "reset" your string with [**(setf fill-pointer)**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_fill_p.htm), and you can add content with **with-output-to-string**, among other ways:

```
(let ((str (make-array '(0)
                       :element-type 'base-char
                       :adjustable t
                       :fill-pointer 0)))

  ;; Temporarily create a character output stream that directs its
  ;; output to the underlying string that we created, and write "hello
  ;; world!"  to it.
  (with-output-to-string (s str)
    (format s "hello world!"))

  ;; prints "hello world", sets the FILL-POINTER back to 0, and then
  ;; prints "".
  (print str)
  (setf (fill-pointer str) 0)
  (print str)

  ;; But note that the underlying array
  ;; and the content that you put into
  ;; it are still available.  While LENGTH
  ;; returns 0, ARRAY-TOTAL-SIZE reports
  ;; 12, and you can still just AREF to
  ;; get the old content.
  (print (length str))                  ;=> 0
  (print (array-total-size str))        ;=> 12
  (print (aref str 6))                  ;=> #\w

  ;; update content using vector push extend, and print "abcde".
  (vector-push-extend #\a str)
  (vector-push-extend #\b str)
  (vector-push-extend #\c str)
  (vector-push-extend #\d str)
  (vector-push-extend #\e str)
  (print str)                           ;=> "abcde"

  ;; Or set the fill pointer manually, possibly setting content in the
  ;; array before or after.  Note that you can (SETF AREF) elements in
  ;; the vector that aren't in the active portion.  First, we confirm
  ;; that the fill pointer is at 5, then set an element at 8 (past the
  ;; fill pointer), then set the fill pointer to 10, and set an
  ;; element at 6 (before the fill pointer).  All these changes affect
  ;; the vector contents.
  (print (fill-pointer str))            ;=> 5
  (setf (aref str 8) #\X)
  (setf (fill-pointer str) 10)
  (setf (aref str 6) #\Y)
  (print str)                           ;=> "abcde YoXl"

  )
```